# Bootstrap 3 header looking incorrectly on Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with coding a header, the header I have coded is being displayed well in Chrome, but its not in Firefox. (In Firefox its a bit Missy). 
(the header is responsive and coded using Bootstrap 3)

photos explains the problem:

The header In Chrome: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/M4cJh3J.png] (nice and clean)

The header In Firefox: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/KZJlUZ2.png] (missed up)

this problem happened when I made the top bar.

my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom4.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- top bar starts -->

        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <ul class="social-icons">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <ul class="sign-options pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#">sign in</a></li>
                            <li><span>/</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#">sign up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- end row -->
            </div> <!-- end container -->
        </div> <!-- end top-bar div -->

        <!-- top bar ends -->


        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">

                <!-- Brand and toggle-->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#greeny-header">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand img-responsive"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- End Brand and toggle-->

                <!-- navbar collapse -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="greeny-header">

                    <!-- navigation list -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Who are we</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end navigation list -->

                </div>
                <!-- end navbar-collapse -->

            </div><!-- end container -->
        </nav>


        <!-- Javasctipt --> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the CSS

```
    /*
*********************
* =header
*********************
*/
.navbar-default{
    height: 100px;
}
#greeny-header{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.navbar-header a{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-header a{
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-nav span{
    font-size: 25px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
}

/*
*********************
* =top-bar
*********************
*/

.top-bar{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    height: 40px;
}
.social-icons{
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.social-icons li{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.social-icons span{
    color: #a59f9a;
}
.social-icons span:hover{
    color: #e1e1e1;
}
.sign-options{
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.sign-options li{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 7px;
}

.sign-options a{
    color: #b3aca7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sign-options a:hover{
    color: #e1e1e1;
}
.sign-options span{
    color: #d79450;
}
```

Comment: Please only add the code for the problem section and add the css too, what can we do only with html ?

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap any div with container div inside to row. I did it in this [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgtfv).
Basically used your code and wrapper every section into `row` class. I tested with browser stack and it looks fine now.

I added the link to new screenshot "Win XP, FF v15.0". [Here to screenshot](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0995f9df057428e73a585e5bb65dd354723e4d45)

Comment: Hi hadi! thank you so much, the mess is gone, but the row created two problems, i tried to solve them but i couldn't, 1- there's a space between the top-bar and the header 2- there's an x axis scroll bar. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `float : left` property to the logo style.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I love Firebug.  Looking at the computed styles and the layout will give you your answer right away.  There are two usual suspects in this type of problem: 1) the display styles are not set to inline; or 2) There is a problem with the float.